# Can I organize Doctrine entities or their mapping files into subfolders?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, yaml

I have tried this directory structure for my mapping files:

```
/config/doctrine/Place.orm.yml
/config/doctrine/Place/Type.orm.yml
/config/doctrine/Place/Price.orm.yml
```

And have pointed to the corresponding Entity in my mapping file like this:

```
Project\TestBundle\Entity\Place\Type:
  type: entity
  table: place_type
  id:
    id:
      type: integer
      generator: { strategy:AUTO }
  fields:
    name:
      type: string
      length: 255
```

But this returns an error. The system can't seem to detect the mapping file for Entity.

Comment: I have never seen entities in sub-directories of `Project\TestBundle\Entity\` directory. Are they recognized and loaded by Symfony2?

Comment: I used this in Doctrine, but for symfony this is doesn't work

Comment: So I think that the path at the beginning of the file is wrong, it should be `Project\TestBundle\Entity\PlaceType` or another name, as long as the file is in the `Entity` folder.

Comment: Yes, I can do this but how to make structure?

Comment: What structure? Inheritance of entities? Associate entities in order to make joins between tables?

Comment: Project\TestBundle\Entity\Matherial.php
Project\TestBundle\Entity\Matherial\Category.php
Project\TestBundle\Entity\Matherial\Type.php
How to configure this in yaml? I have expirience with doctrine but but never worked with yaml.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know, but I think you should just place Entity files in the `Entity/` directory and it will works. In my opinion, trying to place them elsewhere is just a waste of time and have no benefit.

Comment: See this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21052273/doctrine-query-class-not-in-entity-directory

Comment: @Andrey Tarykin I think this [example](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/7cpx/using-multiple-mysql-entity-managers-for-multiple-bundles-and-databases) is your starting point. It uses two bundles so you just need assume that they are different folders for entities and modify the example accordingly for your needs. It should be easy.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Long story short, this is possible.

If you have folder structure inside your bundle's Entity folder, it's simple. You have to name your ORM files using entity namespace part below of Entity namespace and replacing `\` with `.`.

So if, for example, you have `Project\TestBundle\Entity\Place\Type` entity, the ORM file (located in `config/doctrine` folder inside bundle) will have name `Place.Type.orm.yml`.

If you want to use as Doctrine entities classes from outside of Entity folder (or even outside of the bundle folder), it gets a little bit complicated, but still possible. Doctrine Bundle allows to define custom mapping locations for your classes in its configuration.

Again - example. If you have your entities inside of `Project\Test` namespace (in folder `src/Project/Test`), you can define mapping like this:

> app/config/config*.yml

```
doctrine:
  orm:
    MyCustomDomain:
          mapping:              true
          type:                 yml
          dir:                  %kernel.root_dir%/config/projecttest
          alias:                ProjectTest
          prefix:               Project\Test
          is_bundle:            false
```

In fact, Doctrine Bundle does something similar automatically, that's why you can put all of your classes in Entity subfolder and fear no more.

The prefix is namespace prefix. Folder is the path to folder with configuration files. Alias is interesting - it allows to use simpler object names in DQL queries and mapping files. Symfony's `TestBundle:Test` syntax works on the same premise - `TestBundle`is the alias for all entities in TestBundle. `is_bundle` tells Doctrine, that the entities are outside of Symfony bundle and require a little bit different treatment.

There are some caveats in defining your own mapping. Mapper works using 'first match' rule on prefix. So if you declare your mapping on too broad namespace prefix, it can override other mappings.

Nevertheless, it is useful sometimes. For example, if you want to map classes from "foreign" library directly to Doctrine. Or are creating a library not completely tied to Symfony and want to keep some of your classes outside of the bundle.

Answer (score 12):

If you want to organize your doctrine Entities into subfolders

for example: `src/AppBundle/Entity/subfolder/MyEntity.php`

then the corresponding ORM file should look like:

`src/Resources/config/Doctrine/subfolder.MyEntity.orm.yml`

Don't make subfolders inside `src/Resources/config/Doctrine/`*

***Note:** If you have a look at the [Doctrine config docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineBundle/configuration.html) it looks like it may be possible to configure a different location for your orm.yml file using:

```
doctrine:
      orm:
        # An array of mappings, which may be a bundle name or     something else
        mapping_name:
              mapping:              true
              type:                 ~
              dir:                  ~
              alias:                ~
              prefix:               ~
              is_bundle:            ~
```

but I have not tried this. maybe someone else can confirm to improve this answer?

Comment: `subfolder.MyEntity.orm.yml` – THIS. Thanks a million, did not see this documented anywhere. Makes complete sense in retrospect.

Comment: subfolder.MyEntity.orm.yml - You just saved my life! Many thx <3

Answer (score 1):

with @ORM annotations all you need is ::class,
here is example:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=User::class)
 */
private User $accountant;
```

don't forget to import User like this

```
use App\Entity\Subfolder\User;
```